# Pass data from one View to another ASP.NET CORE MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am in doupt and little bit confussing and try to pass data from one View to another. The scenario is the following. I have `Ticket Model` and I have button open discussion. In button discussion I want to display some data from `Ticket.cs Model`

**TicketView**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fH0Gh.jpg)

DiscussionView

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LPUmq.jpg)

I want to display TicketType, DateTime, and Description in `Discussion` View from `TicketView`

So far I create `ViewModel` but I have no idea is this good approach or not ?

```
public class DiscussionVM
    {
        public Ticket Ticket { get; set; }

        public Discussion Discussion { get; set; }

        public ApplicationUser User { get; set; }

        public TicketType TicketType { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: The ViewModel is fine. From the TicketView, once a user presses your button, you need to call an endpoint on your controller that will build the data for that DiscussionVM and return your DiscussionView.